# Counting core data to many relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to sort by an aggregate function in Core Data. I've a model that has entities Recipe and Food, with a relationship of many-to-many between them. I start with a query that lists recipes that contain foods I've listed. Thus far I've got:

```
NSExpression* key_path_exp = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"recipeName"];
NSExpression *countExpression =  [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"count:"
                                                           arguments: [NSArray arrayWithObject:key_path_exp] ];

// Count the number of specified foods that this recipe contains, by counting the grouped by recipeName
NSExpressionDescription *count_description = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[count_description setName: @"count"];
[count_description setExpression: countExpression];
[count_description setExpressionResultType: NSInteger32AttributeType];

// Which of the columns I'm interested in
NSAttributeDescription* recipe_name_column = [_fetchRequest.entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"recipeName"];
[_fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:recipe_name_column, count_description,  nil]];
// Group by the recipe name
[_fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:recipe_name_column]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@",@"foods",foods];
[_fetchRequest predicate];
// Required for group by
[_fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"healthFactor" ascending:NO];
[_fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
{
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error.localizedDescription, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
```

Which produces the SQL:

```
SELECT t0.ZRECIPENAME, COUNT( t0.ZRECIPENAME) FROM ZRECIPE t0 GROUP BY  t0.ZRECIPENAME ORDER BY t0.ZHEALTHFACTOR DESC
```

And an example of output:

```
Old-school venison pie with juniper, rosemary & bay|5
Oriental pork with noodles|7
Pad Thai|3
Pint of prawns|10
Potato Gnocchi|7
Pumpkin Flan Recipe|12
```

When connecting directly to the sqlite database I can edit the query such that the `ORDER BY` becomes:

```
ORDER BY count(t0.ZRECIPENAME) ASC
```

which produces exactly the results I'm after. But, how can this be implemented in core data using `NSSortDescriptor`?

Can anyone suggest a way of sorting against the result set before models are created? `NSSortDescriptior` will only let me sort by any one of the Entity's keys. Or perhaps there's more efficient sorting solution other than sorting against the `NSDictionary` results. The result sets can be 1000's of rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the convenience method `sortUsingComparator`...

```
    [<<insert Array or Dictionary>> sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(ObjectA *objectA, ObjectB *objectB) {
        NSString *titleA = nil;
        NSString *titleB = nil;

        titleA = [objectA valueForKey:@"titleForObjectA"];
        titleB = [objectB valueForKey:@"titleForObjectB"];

        return [titleA localizedStandardCompare:titleB];
    }];
```

UPDATE: apologies this is a convenience method for `NSMutableArray`.

Although there is a similar method for an `NSDictionary`...

`keysSortedByValueUsingComparator` documentation [here](http://xcdoc://?url=developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/1048/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/index.html), so maybe you can add a comparator block similar to the above into this convenience method?

Comment: This is the method I use which has the downside of sorting only content once it's in memory, albeit sorting in batches to help performance. Sorting on the sqlite query itself would be better.